# Pandas Error while converting Boolean Values into actual values

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

When performing few analysis over my excel data in python. I encounter an error  while running the code to fetch the few data based on my parameter

I have an excel file which is taken as a source for Python pandas. In excel we have a column named "Summary" wherein i need to fetch the records of those Summary which starts/contains "FW:"

The code looks perfect for me, i did run the code and got the output in Boolean Values. When converting the Boolean Values into the complete Records. I encounter an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel('Desktop/VGCS06.xlsx)
data['Summary'].str.contains('FW:')
```

## OUTPUT for the above in Boolean Values, wherein there are few False followed by True.

```
data[data['Summary].str.contains('FW:')]
```

## Error for the above code

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 data[data['Summary'].str.contains('FW:')]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in **getitem**(self, key)
   2680         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   2681             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2682             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2683         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   2684             return self._getitem_frame(key)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2707     def _getitem_array(self, key):
   2708         # also raises Exception if object array with NA values
-> 2709         if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
   2710             # warning here just in case -- previously **setitem** was
   2711             # reindexing but **getitem** was not; it seems more reasonable to

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py in is_bool_indexer(key)
    105             if not lib.is_bool_array(key):
    106                 if isna(key).any():
--> 107                     raise ValueError('cannot index with vector containing '
    108                                      'NA / NaN values')
    109                 return False

ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: use : `data[data['Summary].str.contains('FW:',na=False)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have `np.nan` in columns

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'Summary':['FW:','','FW:',np.nan]})
data[data['Summary'].str.contains('FW:').fillna(False)]
  Summary
0     FW:
2     FW:
```

More info , `str.contains` will return `NaN` when the original data is `NaN`

```
data['Summary'].str.contains('FW:')
0     True
1    False
2     True
3      NaN
Name: Summary, dtype: object
```

---

Recommend by anky_91

```
data['Summary'].str.contains('FW:',na=False)
```

Comment: we can specify `na=False` inside `str.contains()` think it would be more straight forward. :)

Comment: @anky_91 you are right

Comment: Bingo, that worked, Awesome :)

Comment: @SiddharthSureshNayak if it is work would you like accept it? Check mark at the left